# Embarcadero RAD Delphi 10.3.3, cannot compile my app with Box2D library for 64-bits Android

Tags: android, delphi, compilation, 64-bit, box2d

Cannot compile my App for Android 64-bit with Delphi 10.3.3.
My App is using Box2D library.
While compile I get following errors:

```
[DCC Error] E2597 C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\android-ndk-r17b\toolchains\aarch64-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows\aarch64-linux-android\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lFlatBox2D
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\android-ndk-r17b\toolchains\aarch64-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows\aarch64-linux-android\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lgnustl_static
```

Compilation for Android 32-bit of same App is successful.
Compilation of another my (simple) App for Android 64-bits works fine.

So, I realized, that problem is only with Box2D for Android 64-bits used in my App.

Then I also tested compilation of Box2D TestBed App that is coming with RAD (here `...\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\Physics\TestBed\`) - the same issue - it is compiled successfully for Android 32-bits, but same error when I'm compiling TestBed for Android 64-bits!

Please help. Thousands of lines of code in my App already, and now it is full stop - can't build it for Android 64-bits [**scared**]

**UPDATE1**

Second error "cannot find -lgnustl_static" fixed by adding path `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\android-ndk-r17b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\libs\arm64-v8a` into menu Tools->Options, then 'SDK Manager'->NDK->'Android SDK 25.2.5 64-bits'-> value for 'Delphi NDK Library path'.

However, the first problem '**cannot find -lFlatBox2D**'still exists.
I found only 2 files of library `libFlatBox2D.a` on my computer, it is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\lib\android\debug
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\lib\android\release
```

Both paths I added to the same 'Delphi NDK Library path' at SDK Manager for Android 64bit.
However, now getting error message `skipping incompatible libFlatBox2D.a when searching for -lFlatBox2D` for each of these paths.

So the question now - where to find a compatible libFlatBox2D.a that required for Android 64bits?

**UPDATE2:**

Hm... and in following 2 `android64` paths do not have any libFlatBox2D.a files.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\lib\android64\debug
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\lib\android64\release
```

Does it mean, that 10.3.3 Delphi installation is missing 64-bits Box2D android library?

**UPDATE3:**

As answered by @Stefanos , now I have 64bit version of libFlatBox2D.a.
But now while compiling I receiving count of 1700 linker errors about Box2D names , all of them similar to below:

```
[DCC Error] E2597 C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\Physics\TestBed\Android64\Debug\Box2D.Common.o: In function `Box2d::Common::Create_b2Draw_delegate(System::DelphiInterface<Box2d::Common::Ib2Draw>)':
  Box2D.Common:(.text._ZN5Box2d6Common22Create_b2Draw_delegateEN6System15DelphiInterfaceINS0_7Ib2DrawEEE[_ZN5Box2d6Common22Create_b2Draw_delegateEN6System15DelphiInterfaceINS0_7Ib2DrawEEE]+0x0): undefined reference to `Create_b2Draw_delegate'
  C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\Physics\TestBed\Android64\Debug\Box2D.Common.o: In function `Box2d::Common::Destroy_b2Draw_delegate(NativeUInt)':
  Box2D.Common:(.text._ZN5Box2d6Common23Destroy_b2Draw_delegateE10NativeUInt[_ZN5Box2d6Common23Destroy_b2Draw_delegateE10NativeUInt]+0x0): undefined reference to `Destroy_b2Draw_delegate'
  C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\Physics\TestBed\Android64\Debug\Box2D.Common.o: In function `Box2d::Common::b2Version_Create()':
  Box2D.Common:(.text._ZN5Box2d6Common16b2Version_CreateEv[_ZN5Box2d6Common16b2Version_CreateEv]+0x0): undefined reference to `b2Version_b2Version'
  C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\Physics\TestBed\Android64\Debug\Box2D.Common.o: In function `Box2d::Common::b2BlockAllocator_Create()':
  Box2D.Common:(.text._ZN5Box2d6Common23b2BlockAllocator_CreateEv[_ZN5Box2d6Common23b2BlockAllocator_CreateEv]+0x0): undefined reference to `b2BlockAllocator_b2BlockAllocator_1'
  C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\Physics\TestBed\Android64\Debug\Box2D.Common.o: In function `Box2d::Common::b2BlockAllocator_Destroy(NativeUInt)':
  Box2D.Common:(.text._ZN5Box2d6Common24b2BlockAllocator_DestroyE10NativeUInt[_ZN5Box2d6Common24b2BlockAllocator_DestroyE10NativeUInt]+0x0): undefined reference to `b2BlockAllocator_dtor'
etc...etc...
```

**UPDATE4: Current status**

I'm looking now for original **libFlatBox2D.a** library file for **Android 64-bits** (Delphi 10.3.3). If anyone has it, please share it with me.

The above attempts were not successful. An 'original' 64bits libFlatBox2D.a is required, which is not in my installation of RAD 10.3.3...

**UPDATE5:**

Embarcadero QA created a ticket:
*https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-27762*
Will wait from their solution.

Comment: See this note: [Specify Android NDK Library Path for Apps that Contain TClientDataSet](http://docwiki.appmethod.com/appmethod/1.16/topics/en/Release_Notes_for_1.16#Specify_Android_NDK_Library_Path_for_Apps_that_Contain_TClientDataSet)

Comment: @LURD Thank you for the advice. Now one of two errors have fixed. However, still problem with libFlatBox2D.a for Android 64bits compilation - please see UPDATE above. Who knows how to fix this? where to find compatible libFlatBox2D.a?

Comment: Did you add "FlatBox2D" (i.e. libFlatBox2D.a) to the "additionally linked libraries" project linker option? Found the reference here: https://github.com/FMXExpress/Firemonkey/blob/master/Embarcadero/XE8/CPP/Physics/TestBed/DebugDraw.cpp

Comment: This is the QP report. Keep an eye on it - we'll see if we can just post the binaries on the bug report. https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-27762

10.4 should have it as normal.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new Package with name FlatBox2D, add all FlatBox units from ..\studio\20.0\source\FlatBox2D and compile it for Android64.

I have created the package and compiled both debug and release versions for Android64 with Delphi 10.3.3. In the link below you will find the new package files and the Android64 folder where you can find the libFlatBox2D.a for Debug and Release. Just copy the .a file to the corresponding folder in ..\studio\20.0\lib\Android64.

You can always compile the package on your own by just copying the FlatBox2D.dpr and FlatBox2D.dproj files in ..\studio\20.0\source\FlatBox2D, load the dpr in Delphi and compile it for Android64...

Stefanos

[FlatBox2D.zip](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/dc05d12b427e1214eaa26a48f2a0589620200229175425/b16c81)

Comment: Thank you for sharing knowledge! Now error about missing libFlatBox2D.a gone.
But now on compiling (truing with TestBed)  I'm getting 1773 linking errors of this type:
`[DCC Error] E2597 ...\TestBed\Android64\Debug\Box2D.Common.o: In function Box2d::Common::Create_b2Draw_delegate(System::DelphiInterface<Box2d::Common::Ib2Draw>)':
  Box2D.Common:(.text._ZN5Box2d6Common22Create_b2Draw_delegateEN6System15DelphiInterfaceINS0_7Ib2DrawEEE[_ZN5Box2d6Common22Create_b2Draw_delegateEN6System15DelphiInterfaceINS0_7Ib2DrawEEE]+0x0): undefined reference to `Create_b2Draw_delegate'`

Comment: Please help, as my knowledge of Delphi compiler is not enough to resolve this issue... I searched internet and only found advise that need to change to NDK version 26, so I changes to `\Embarcadero\Studio\android-ndk-r17b\platforms\android-26` in SDK Manager , but still same count of 1773 errors about `undefined reference to ...` Box2D symbols...

Comment: PS. As per your advise, I compiled Box2D on my computer (the resulting compiled  libraries size a bit different than in you archive). But still same 1700 errors...

Comment: After some further digging i realized that you actually need the original box2d library compiled for Android64 (FlatBox2D.a), which you do not have. The units in Delphi source directory are just the import units to the c++ original library. So compiling the units in Delphi is not the way to go.

Comment: The errors that you get are because the actual functions are not implemented in the Delphi produced FlatBox2d.a file.

Comment: Does that original 64bits libFlatBox2d.a exists in the world?